# Question asks for a "shortlist column" and I'm getting an error about it

Tags: sql

I'm doing a SQL problem in CodeWars ([instructions here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csutz.png)) and I'm getting confused by this part:

> To aid the scribes, return the *firstname* and *lastname* column
>   concatenated, separated by a space, into a single *shortlist* column,
>   and capitalise the first letter of each name.

What do they mean by a "shortlist column"? I thought it meant returning a single column but I'm getting an [error about it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pamht.png)

Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT INITCAP(firstname) || ' ' || INITCAP(lastname)

FROM Elves

WHERE firstname LIKE '%tegil%' OR lastname LIKE '%*%'
```

If anyone could shed light on the situation, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: It mentions shortlist of candidates in the instructions so it's not a particular database column type or anything like that.

Maybe select ... AS shortlist (i.e. into a field named shortlist).

What rbdms flavour are you using?

Comment: Note how column names are in italics in the question. They want a column literally called `shortlist`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT(INITCAP(firstname)," ",INITCAP(lastname)) AS shortlist FROM Elves WHERE firstname LIKE '%tegil%' OR lastname LIKE '%astar%';
```

Comment: Technically wrong. It should be `... lastname LIKE '%astar%'`.

Comment: I took the LIKE clause directly from the OPs original query.  Why astar instead of *?

Comment: Because that's what the question says.

Comment: @ChrisFNZ yep that was it---the _astar_ thing threw me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the definition of [`INITCAP`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions065.htm):

> INITCAP returns char, with the first letter of each word in uppercase,
>   all other letters in lowercase

So you can apply INITCAP() to the concatenated name:

```
SELECT INITCAP(firstname || ' ' || lastname) as shortlist
FROM Elves
WHERE firstname LIKE '%tegil%' OR lastname LIKE '%astar%'
```

You misunderstood the requirement for the last name: it's not *a star* but *astar* that the last name must contain.